# While copy pasting row in Quick edit view error is coming up as "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: custom-list

There is an issue while copy-paste an existing row in SharePoint list through quick edit. 
The list has lot of columns and among them 15 columns are of lookup, people and group columns.
The view where copy paste is done is having 3 lookup columns and 4 people and group column. While copying a row to another blank row it copies the row and red icon appears saying: "Value does not fall within the expected range". When stop editing and while choosing "Discard my changes" The row is added to the view.
The error "Value does not fall within the expected range" does not come up when a particular look up column is removed. When this column is there the error remains.
The list view lookup threshold is default that is 8.

Any help or suggestion how this can be resolved is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem when trying to `copy/paste` into SharePoint 2013 quick edit when creating new records.

This odd thing is that the Central Admin `'List View Lookup threshold'` setting is 12. I can create views with 12 lookup columns, I can copy/paste into existing records with data for 12 lookup columns.

However when I try to copy/paste into empty rows to create new records I get the error

> 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

Unless I decrease the number of columns in the copy/paste -

By trial and error I found the limit is `8 lookup columns` (despite the actual threshold setting being 12).

**The workaround is to just copy/paste more than once to transfer all the data.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution:

http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/05/sharepoint-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-exception-in-spfieldmap-getcolumnnumber/

Since you're trying to copy - paste items, so I don't think the view has something to do with the error. The query itself that goes to the database is above the List View Lookup threshold, so you're trying to copy-paste an item and all other lookup field (even people picker fields).

Comment: Yes you are correct the List View LookUp threshold settings was 8 and this was causing the issue